# Yii2. ListView pagination issue inside bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, pagination, modal-dialog, yii2

I insert the content inside modal with jquery as following:

```
$('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
```

In my controller I handle the request:

```
public function actionVotes($id)
    {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //some magic with model
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('viewVotes', [
                'model' => $model,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My models render in ListView. And when I try to change a page of ListView inside Modal, Modal closes and page content renders on new page via Ajax(without header footer etc.) How to avoid Modal close and reflect the content from controller not to new page but back to Modal?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a pjax widget? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html

Answer (score 2):

I solved an issue by adding following jquery code to the end of Modal content:

```
$(".pagination li a").click(function(){
        $("#modalContent").load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
});
```